# mongodb shell $inc converts int to double

Tags: mongodb

Using a 1 liner to updateMany records via $inc in mongodb via mongo shell, I find that the integer field I'm touching is converted to a double. I understand that the shell uses javascript and that's the reason. My question: Is there a way to continue to use a 1-liner to do this update by somehow passing in the NumberInt or do I need something else?
Given:

> > {
> >       _id: 1,
> >       sku: "abc123",
> >       quantity: 10,
> >       metrics: {
> >         orders: 2,
> >         ratings: 3.5
> >       }
> >     }

I then try the 1-liner.

```
db.products.update(
   { sku: "abc123" },
   { $inc: { quantity: -2, "metrics.orders": 1 } }
)
```

The quantity should be 8 not 8.0 and metrics.orders should be 3 not 3.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To preserve the original integer data type, you need to pass the `$inc` values as `NumberInt`:

```
db.products.update(
   { sku: "abc123" },
   { $inc: { quantity: NumberInt(-2), "metrics.orders": NumberInt(1) } }
)
```

Comment: For Atlas function you can use BSON.Int32:
db.products.update(
   { sku: "abc123" },
   { $inc: { quantity: BSON.Int32(-2), "metrics.orders": BSON.Int32(1) } }
)